# Is there a way to integrate revisioning with Panels + CTools content types?

Tags: panels, chaos-tool-suite

I'm using [CTools content types](http://www.pixelite.co.nz/article/building-custom-content-panes-aka-ctools-content-types-panels-3-and-drupal-7) to make highly customized Panels panes. The panes together form a Panels Node (I'm using the Panels default module for this).

The Panels node itself can be revisioned, but these revisions do not include changes to the content that lives in the panes. It seems that *the content of the panes themselves* cannot be revisioned.

Is there a way to use revisions/workflow/workbench/anything to control the publishing flow of the panes?

[image]

Comment: Hello. Answer to your question is most certainly *yes*. If you want more elaborate answer, please rephrase your question. Also, if you wrote your own ctools content type plugin, remember that by help center questions about improving your code, where you don't show your code, are off-topic. Also, requests for online resources are off-topic, and writing a general manual about integrating custom content types with revisioning may be a bit too broad.

Comment: I probably don't quite understand what you are doing, how does the need arise to revision ctools content types?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure how to be clearer. @Letharion, I'm not trying to revision the "types" per se, I'm trying to revision the content that's in there. In a typical workflow situation, you'd create a new revision anytime you edit the node. But these are not nodes -- so when I edit the content in the pane, no revisioning happens. Make sense?

Comment: @Entendu I pinged you in the chat, if you find your way over there we can try to hash it out. :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I can't think of any simple way to do what you want.

I would probably have solved it by having the content type pull it's content from the entity they are displayed on instead.

It's possible that [fieldable panel panes](https://drupal.org/project/fieldable_panels_panes) could be useful to you.

In the end, if you *really* need revisioning on the the content type settings form, you're gonna have to implement it yourself. Since the form is a standard Drupal form, I would try doing it with a node type as backend, instead of doing the whole thing from scratch. You should be able to just load up the edit form for a node, and re-use most of the functionality.

Comment: For those unaware, @Letharion is a co-maintainer of Panels, so this is likely a definitive answer.

Comment: There's still a lot of things I don't know about the Ctools/Panels collection of modules. Merlinofchaos (and many others) have written a lot of code. :)